# How to alert on metrics with a high cardinality in prometheus

Tags: prometheus, metrics

when trying to create an alert on high metric cardinality with the expression `count by(__name__) ({__name__=~".+"}) > 50` I get the error: `vector contains metrics with the same labelset after applying rule labels`.

As the expression works when using it directly in prometheus, I wonder if there is an actual way to use it in an alert?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution for this issue, as I was trying it myself.

**TL;DR**

Use this promQL expression for alerting on metric cardinality:

```
label_replace(count by(__name__) ({__name__=~".+"}), "name", "$1", "__name__", "(.+)") > 50
```

**Long Version**

The issue as stated in the Prometheus error message. After the metric vector is converted to a vector of the alert, no labels differ and therefore are duplicated.
This means

```
vector A ( metric_a{label=test}, metric_b{label=test} )
```

is converted in

```
vector B ( alert_a{label=test}, alert_a{label=test})
```

and that is why you have duplicates

( caveat: that is at least my understanding)
By adding a new label with the metric name itself, you create a unique label set.